# Install MxNet from sources on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mxnet

I need to install an older version of MXNet - 0.7.0, which is no longer available through pip. The source code for the older versions is available here https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/releases?after=v0.9.3a, however I am unable to compile the code using make:

```
Makefile:23: mshadow/make/mshadow.mk: No such file or directory
Makefile:24: /home/usr/incubator-mxnet-0.7.0/dmlc-core/make/dmlc.mk: No such file or directory
Makefile:86: /home/usr/incubator-mxnet-0.7.0/ps-lite/make/ps.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/home/usr/incubator-mxnet-0.7.0/ps-lite/make/ps.mk'.  Stop.
```

How can I install it? Is there any more straightforward way to install an older version of MXNet?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the submodules that MXNet depends on. Follow the instructions [here](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/install/index.html), except that for step 4 (Download MXNet sources and build MXNet core shared library), replace

`git clone --recursive https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet`

with the following commands:

`git clone --no-checkout https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet
cd incubator-mxnet
git checkout v0.7.0 -b v0.7.0
git submodule update --init`

Answer (score 0):

**Install from source code**

**Download MXNet source code from GitHub**

```
$ git clone --recursive https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet
$ cd incubator-mxnet
$ git checkout 1.3.0
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
$ make -j USE_OPENCV=1
```